# Audio player that can adjust playing speed

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, audio, mediaplayer

Please recommend an audio player for Mac that has features like

- freely available
- can play .wav files
- Adjust the playing speed (ex. 1.1x speed etc)
- (if possible) truncate the audio file (ex. removing the last 5 minutes from the meeting recording)

Comment: I just found that VLC media player satisfies the 1st~3rd conditions. But it does not display how fast it is when I adjust the speed. Does anybody know this?

Comment: I think the speed adjustment interval is too big. I need to more fine-tune speed than VLC does.

Comment: Samsung Music lets you take the speed up to 2X under "Settings". I checked both Mac and iOS stores. Mysteriously not there, not that I expected it to be. Android and Windows have it.

Answer (score 9):

The VLC media player is probably best suited.

- It is Free
- It plays .wav (and almost 100% of anything else out there)
- It shows the Playback Speed settings.

[image]

- It allows speed setting as fine as 0.04 X increments.

Comment: My God, it's full of stars! VLC goes up to to *4X speed*. I'd never tried it on audio.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `-r` to change the playback rate with `afplay`:

```
afplay -r 1.1 file.wav
```